# PHP: mod_rewrite if query contains value

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Recently I solved my issue with mod_rewrite to redirect a domain to a subfolder. Now that I've fixed my original issue, I've hit a another wall.

Here is an example structure:

```
/
/index.php
/content/
/content/styles.css
/domain/
/domain/index.php
```

For simplicity, `/domain/` is the current and top-most folder. **In `/domain/index.php` I am trying to access `/content/styles.css`. How can I accomplish this?** Assume there is no web link to the previous directories. Also `../` does not work as `../` returns the same directory as `./`.

I thought of a way, but my .htaccess skills aren't very strong and I don't want to spend hours or days piecing together an answer. Let's say I have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content/styles.css" />
```

If I am right, `href` performs a request for the file. How can I use .htaccess to capture the request and point it to the correct folder? Like if the query string looks like `^/content/(.*)$`, and rewrite it back one directory to access `../content` instead.

Hopefully this made some type of sense.

Comment: just to clarify, is `/content/` inside `/domain/`. eg `/domain/content/` ?

Comment: @Ben, no. Assume `/` is root. Both `domain/` and `content/` are subdirectories of `/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a dummy `/domain/content` directory with another .htaccess file which has something like

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /content/$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use an Alias:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/domain"
    Alias /content "/content"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Where would this go? If it's for .htaccess, does it go into the (root) `/` or the `/domain/` .htaccess?

Comment: You have to put it in your httpd.conf (or in an include file); check this: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#alias

Answer (score 1):

if `/content/` is NOT inside `/domain/` and `/domain/` is your `DOCUMENT_ROOT` on your webserver, then you can't access the `/content/` folder at all using a `<link>` tag & mod_rewrite.

You could access it via PHP and include it's contents, but that's a different story.

Answer (score 0):

I considered that;

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

exist in your `.htaccess` file.
Why aren't you trying like that?

```
$dir = dirname(__FILE__);
$link = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
// $link = preg_replace('/^www\./i', '', $link);
```

for hrefs;

```
href="<?php echo $link . '/content/content.css'; ?>"
```

for imports;

```
include($dir . '/example.php');
```